# Sorting an array: Firstly by 1 element in a defined order, Then by the total of 2 other elements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've looked at numerous examples on SO, but I'm unable to find a solution to this problem. I have a large array and I need to sort this by 2 elements.

> - Firstly, by a priority field in a custom order: S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,D,NS
> - Secondly, by 2 fields in the array added together. (This bit is working.)

I've made a sorting function which will sort by both of the above, however, it sorts D and NS before S1-S5 since D comes first alphabetically.
- I therefore need to define an array which contains the custom order I want to sort by. Please can anyone help?

The function I'm using is:

```
function compdaily($a, $b) {
    if ($a['Priority'] == $b['Priority']) 
    {
        return ($a['Value1'] + $a['Value2']) < ($b['Value1'] + $b['Value2']);
    }
    return strcmp($a['Priority'], $b['Priority']);
}
```

I then call above function in this manner:

```
usort($Array, 'compdaily');
```

Which brings the items out in this order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 1234
            [Priority] => D
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 456
            [Priority] => NS
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 124
            [Priority] => S1
            [Value1] => 200
            [Value2] => 200
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 1235
            [Priority] => S1
            [Value1] => 100
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 1230
            [Priority] => S2
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 123495
            [Priority] => S3
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 123498
            [Priority] => S3
            [Value1] => 100
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 12345
            [Priority] => S4
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
)
```

However, I need them in this order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 124
            [Priority] => S1
            [Value1] => 200
            [Value2] => 200
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 1235
            [Priority] => S1
            [Value1] => 100
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 1230
            [Priority] => S2
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 123495
            [Priority] => S3
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 123498
            [Priority] => S3
            [Value1] => 100
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 12345
            [Priority] => S4
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 1234
            [Priority] => D
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [SomeID] => 456
            [Priority] => NS
            [Value1] => 250
            [Value2] => 100
        )
)
```

I've tried utilising the example at: [Sort an array by multiple keys in a certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519068/sort-an-array-by-multiple-keys-in-a-certain-order)
But I was unable to get this to work alongside the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `$a['Priority']` directly in sorting, could use a lookup table to get the actual order

something like...

```
$mapp = array('S1'=>1, 'S2'=>2, 'S3'=>3, 'S4'=>4, 'S5'=>5, 'D'=>6, 'NS'=>7);

function compdaily($a, $b) {
    global $mapp;
    ...
    return ($mapp[$a['Priority']] < $mapp[$b['Priority']]);
}
```

(the if statement doesn't need changing as can directly compare the strings for equality)

Comment: Hi Barry. Thanks for the reply..

I had to change the return to: 
return strcmp($mapp[$a['Priority']], $mapp[$b['Priority']]); 

After this, it worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: why? In that case will have to be careful if add more than 10 items in the list, as doing string comparisons on numbers doesnt work. If was just getting results backwards, maybe you jsut need to change the comparison operator to `>` (rather than `<`)